# py2app plist app info not showing up when looking at About app

Tags: python, tkinter, py2app, info.plist

I'm trying to create an App using py2app and everything is working fine except that I can't get the info from my specified plist to show when I select the About  section from the menu. The information shows up when I right click and select Get Info, but not inside the app. When I click on About TextTools (the name of my app) I'm shown the info for Tcl/Tk instead.

Here's what I'm getting:

[image]

Here is my setup.py file:

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['TextTools.py']
DATA_FILES = ['TextAnalysis.py', 'CustomText.py', 'ResultTree.py']
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True,
 'iconfile': '/Users/howe1rp/Desktop/TT_local/TextTools_local/TextTools/man.icns',
 'plist': {
 'CFBundleName': 'TextTools',
 'CFBundleShortVersionString':'0.0.1', 
 'CFBundleVersion': '0.0.1', 
 'CFBundleIdentifier':'com.rh.TextTools', 
 'NSHumanReadableCopyright': '@ My Name 2014'}}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    py_modules=['TextAnalysis', 'CustomText', 'ResultTree'],
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using Tkinter within your Python app.  The Cocoa-based Aqua Tk on OS X creates the base menu options and includes a default `About` menu item.  It is not documented very well in Tk, but it is possible to override the default Cocoa `About` by overriding the default Tk `tkAboutDialog` command.  Here's a very simple example which uses the built-in Aqua Tk `standardAboutPanel`.

```
try:
    from tkinter import *   # Python 3
except ImportError:
    from Tkinter import *   # Python 2

def new_file():
    # ...
    pass

def about_dialog():
    root.tk.call('tk::mac::standardAboutPanel')

root = Tk()
win = Toplevel(root)
menubar = Menu(win)
menu_file = Menu(menubar)
# ...
menubar.add_cascade(menu=menu_file, label='File')
# ...
menu_file.add_command(label='New', command=new_file)
# ...
root.createcommand('tkAboutDialog', about_dialog)
win['menu'] = menubar
root.mainloop()
```

There's more info [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.tkinter/3149).

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm still not able to get this to work. I deleted all other menus I had so I'm left with only the apple menu and it's still not working. It just ends up creating a new menu with the `About` menu item. Could you provide an example of how I would implement this?

Comment: I've done a little more research and updated the answer with a very simple example.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow this was much simpler than I thought. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for this great answer. I've seen that you added some additional menu bar entries to your code, not only the "About" panel. If all you want is to provide a custom "About" panel, here is the stripped down Python 3 version.

```
from tkinter import *

def about_dialog():
    root.tk.call('tk::mac::standardAboutPanel')

root = Tk()
root.createcommand('tkAboutDialog', about_dialog)
root.mainloop()
```